# java annotation for do not invoke overridden method

Tags: java, annotations, overriding, subclass, deprecated

I have two classes Foo and Bar, where Bar extends Foo.

In the superclass, there is a method f().  The subclass overrides this method and purposefully throws an exception so that f() is never invoked on instances of Bar.

```
class Foo {
  public void f() {
     // does something useful
  }

}


class Bar extends Foo {
  @Override
  public void f() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Srsly, thou shalt not");
  }
}
```

Now here is my question:  is there some annotation that I can use on the overridden method that communicates to IDEs such as Eclipse that one shouldn't call it?  I found myself wanting to lightly-abuse the @deprecated tag so that the auto-complete list in Eclipse <strike>crosses the method out</strike> when the user is dealing with an instance of Bar, but I wanted to know if there was a better option.

```
class Bar extends Foo {

  /**
   * @deprecated
   */
  @Override
  public void f() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Srsly, thou shalt not");
  }
}
```

Comment: `UnsupportedOperationException` seems the nearest thing, but I don't think there's an annotation.

Comment: What is the expected method you want to call? If yes call Super class method using super keyword.

Comment: @Boann I thought that might be the case.  You should paste your comment into an answer in case nobody else even understands the question.

Answer (score -2):

No not really as all (non static) methods in Java are virtual and the calls are resolved at runtime. In other words, there's no way for the compiler to detect that Bar's version of the method will be called in runtime.

Comment: I recognize that your answer contains no untrue statements.  Do they pertain to the question in some way?

Answer (score -2):

I would make the function f() private.
That way, it can never be called outside Bar.